# Prettier: Keeping empty lines separating attributes in HTML/JSX HTML

Tags: html, jsx, styled-components, prettier, tsx

So I've been trying to find a way to tell Prettier to keep line breaks between attributes in HTML, for keeping code clear, but I'm coming up empty. I'm working in TypeScript React with Styled Components, don't know if that makes a difference for the answer. I've been wondering if this is a job for Beautify, but since I'm using prettier to auto-format files on commit I'm worried using both might get very messy.

Here is what I'm talking about:

```html
<CustomInput
  value={whatever}

  width="100px"
  height="32px"
  background="#333"
  borderColor="sandybrown"

  onFocus={handleFocus}
  onBlur={handleBlur}
  onChange={evt => setWhatever(evt.target.value)}
/>
```

Notice the empty lines separating the different "categories" of attributes. Prettier automatically removes these. Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Prettifiers aught to remove empty lines in my opinion

Perhaps you can use HTML comments

```html
<CustomInput
  value="{whatever}"
  <!-- formatting -->
  width="100px"
  height="32px"
  background="#333"
  borderColor="sandybrown"
  <!-- event handlers-->
  onFocus={handleFocus}
  onBlur={handleBlur}
  onChange={evt => setWhatever(evt.target.value)}
/>
```

Or just do what is recommended:

```js
const handleFocus = () => {}
const handleBlur = () => {}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const inp = document.querySelector("CustomInput");
  inp.addEventListener("focus", handleFocus);
  inp.addEventListener("blur", handleBlur);
  inp.addEventListener("change", evt => setWhatever(evt.target.value));
});
```

```css
CustomInput {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 32px;
  background: #333;
  border-color: sandybrown;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<CustomInput value="{whatever}">Text</CustomInput>
```

Comment: The comments suggestion is a possible work-around. I'm not sure why I should do the other thing though; while that may be the recommended method in pure JS and some other frameworks, I'm quite sure using attribute-events is the recommendation in React. All the React docs does it, anyway, and with your method I would have to manually clean up event listeners.

Comment: "Prettifiers aught to remove empty lines." I'm also not quite sure why this would be true, since Prettier does not remove empty lines in JavaScript, CSS and such (as it would make the code very messy, it's not a minifier after all).

Comment: My linter certainly does not allow an empty line

Comment: Not even in JS? Like, there's no empty lines anywhere in the file?

Comment: Yes, after a function/method and an end tag but not between attributes

Comment: Ah, yes, okay. I would like it between attributes because it's cleaner when you have 15 attributes on a component, which can happen with Styled Components.

Answer (score 1):

It's indeed supposed to work the way you expect (just like it works in object literals). This is simply not implemented yet. There is [an open pull request](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/pull/6643), but it seems to be abandoned.

Comment: Oh, well good to see they're aware of the problem, at least. Hope they'll get to that PR soon. Thanks for the link.

Comment: They're just a small group of volunteers who can't get to every issue promptly. Help is appreciated.